# Is there a way to improve the run time or optimize Python / Pyspark code?

Tags: python, sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I working on extracting table count information from Azure SQL Server for over 350+ tables. As the system metadata tables are not regularly refreshed so I can't rely upon that. I written the below code to help me achieve the same -

```
import pyodbc
from pyspark.sql.types import *
pyodbc.pooling = False

def get_table_count(query ,server, username, password, database):

  conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
  cursor = conn.cursor()  
  cursor.execute(query)
  row = cursor.fetchone()
  
  columns = StructType([StructField('tableCount', LongType(), True) , StructField('tableName', StringType(), True), StructField('databaseName', StringType(), True)])
  data = [(row[0], row[1], row[2])]  
  df = spark.createDataFrame( data = data,schema = columns)

  cursor.close()
  del cursor
  conn.close()
  
  return df
```

```
import pyspark.sql.functions  as F

dbList = [ SQLServerDB1 , SQLServerDB1 ]

SQLServerDB1_query = ""
SQLServerDB2_query = ""

for db in dbList:
  print("Currently loading for "+db+" database")
  serverName = db + "SQLServerName"
  serverUser = db + "SQLServerUser"
  serverPassword = db + "SQLServerPassword"
  serverDB = db + "SQLServerDB"  
  tables=df.select('target_object').filter(F.col('source') == db).distinct().toPandas()['target_object']

  for tablename in list(tables):
    if tablename != list(tables)[-1]:
      vars()["%s_query"%db] = f" Select count_big(*) as tableCount, '{tablename}' as tableName, '{db}' as databaseName from " + f"{tablename} \n" + " union \n" + vars()["%s_query"%db]
    else:
      vars()["%s_query"%db] = vars()["%s_query"%db] + f" Select count_big(*) as tableCount, '{tablename}' as tableName, '{db}' as databaseName from " + f"{tablename}"
    
    vars()["%s_DF"%db] = get_table_count( vars()["%s_query"%db] , eval(serverName),  eval(serverUser),  eval(serverPassword), eval(serverDB) )

#     exec(f'{db}_DF = get_table_count( vars()["%s_query"%db] , eval(serverName),  eval(serverUser),  eval(serverPassword), eval(serverDB) )')

    
#     print(tablename + " Loaded")
```

Getting Below error -

`('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Parse error at line: 3, column: 1: Incorrect syntax near 'union'. (103010) (SQLExecDirectW)")`

I tried printing the SQL statements and it worked without any issue from SQL Server DB.
Please suggest where am I writing the code incorrectly.

Comment: You can use two queries to do this. The first query retrieves all the table names of interest in your database. With that information you build another query containing a union of your current query (for each table) while also including the table name as a column. If you search for "count rows in all tables" you will see the technique for generating this SQL as well as some shortcuts. In short, let the engine do the work.

Comment: @SMor - Could you please elaborate a bit ?
I'm currently identifying the tables through a pyspark dataframe, and then calling a function to do the count part. Only part I'm bit concerned about is using two for loops and using Pandas to convert tables dataframe to list.

Comment: Counting the rows in a SQL Server table requires scanning some non-filtered index.  If there's not a narrow index, to choose, the whole table will be scanned.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Is there a better way to do this ? Please note, I just have read access to both of the databases. Additionally, at times I'm also getting [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name ***table****. When i tried a count(1) on the table it worked impeccably.

Comment: create a query string by iterating the tablename like Select table1, count_big(1) from table1 uniion Select table2 , count_big(1) from table2 and then pass to do the database as a single string instead of fecthing one by one

Comment: @Rafa - There are over 350+ tables. In addition to that I'm iterating of 2 separate database instances hosted on its respective servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried with the below code and it works. Thanks guys for the suggestions!

```
def get_table_count(query ,server, username, password, database):
  
  jdbc_url = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{server}:1433;databaseName={database}"
  
  df_read = spark.read \
            .format("jdbc") \
            .option("url",jdbc_url) \
            .option("query", query) \
            .option("user", username) \
            .option("password", password) \
            .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
            .load()
  
  df_save = df_read.write.mode('overwrite').parquet('/tmp/' + f"{database}" + '.parquet')
  
  df = spark.read.parquet('/tmp/' + f"{database}" + '.parquet')
    
  return df
```

```
import pyspark.sql.functions  as F

dbList = [ SQLServerDB1 , SQLServerDB1 ]

SQLServerDB1_query = ""
SQLServerDB2_query = ""

for db in dbList:
  print("Currently loading for "+db+" database")
  serverName = db + "SQLServerName"
  serverUser = db + "SQLServerUser"
  serverPassword = db + "SQLServerPassword"
  serverDB = db + "SQLServerDB"  
  tables=df.select('target_object').filter(F.col('source') == db).distinct().toPandas()['target_object']

  for tablename in list(tables):
    if tablename != list(tables)[-1]:
      vars()["%s_query"%db] = f" Select count_big(1) as tableCount, '{tablename}' as tableName, '{db}' as databaseName from " + f"{tablename} \n" + " union \n" + vars()["%s_query"%db]
    else:
      vars()["%s_query"%db] = vars()["%s_query"%db] + f" Select count_big(1) as tableCount, '{tablename}' as tableName, '{db}' as databaseName from " + f"{tablename}"    
    
  print(vars()["%s_query"%db])
    
  vars()["%s_DF"%db] = get_table_count( vars()["%s_query"%db] , eval(serverName),  eval(serverUser),  eval(serverPassword), eval(serverDB) )
  
  vars()["%s_DF"%db].createOrReplaceTempView(f"{db}_tablesCount")
  
  print(f"{db}"+ " Loaded")
```